# Square of subgaussian variable's parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions, gaussian-integral

If a zero-mean variable $X$ satisfies $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}  ] \le e^{\lambda^{2} \sigma^{2}/2}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, (i.e., subgaussian with parameter $\sigma^{2}$), does it follow that 
$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda (X^{2} - \mathbb{E}[X^{2}])}] \le e^{\lambda^{2}\sigma^{4}/2}$?

Comment: I think it's not true. Did you check for $X\sim N(0, 1)$?

Comment: If $X\sim N(0,1)$ then $E e^{\lambda X} = e^{\lambda^2/2}$. However, $E e^{\lambda X^2} = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{\lambda x^2} e^{-x^2/2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and this integral is finite if $\lambda <1/2$ and infinity if $\lambda \geqslant 1/2$.